# Is it possible to use intellisense for an entry from RobotFramework dictionary?

Tags: dictionary, robotframework, intellisense, autosuggest

I'd like to ask if it possible to use intellisense in Visual Studio Code when calling for an entry from a dictionary in Robot Framework. Kind of similar way as when using the Enum there and the intelissense gives you suggestion

[This is how the intellisense suggest for dictionary entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hmmue.png)

[This is how intellisense suggest for enum entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQKZ8.png)

Is it possible to do the same for dictionaries?